# Changing CSS with Jquery, how to keep a part of the rule

Tags: jquery, css

I've a CSS rule.

```
background: url(../images/banner1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

How can I ONLY change the location of the image, and not the other tags in this line?

This is the current Jquery line I am talking about:

```
$('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')'});
```

In this code the location of the image and everything is loaded. But how can I say that;

```
no-repeat center center fixed
```

need to be after this beginning???

**EDIT:**
Because of the reaction from nnnnnn, this is the complete code:

```
var newBg = ['img/banner1.jpg', 'img/banner2.jpg'];
var i = 0;
var rotateBg = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if ( i > 2 ) {
        i = 0;
    }
    $('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')'});
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Does it not work already? You _are_ setting the `backgroundImage` property and not `background` with jQuery.

Comment: works as expected for me

Comment: @nnnnnn hmm, you're right. But no, it isn't working. Maybe there is something wrong with the rest of the code, and not the changing part?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/a5vCn/ - It should be `i >= newBg.length` (or `i >= 2` or `i > 1`, but not `i > 2`), but that doesn't stop it working, it just adds in a blank background in each cycle.

Comment: @nnnnnn jep it seems to work! But one thing; after two images there is a pause without an image. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, that's the `> 2` thing I already mentioned. Or you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/a5vCn/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('body').css('background', 'url(' + newBg[i] + ') no-repeat center center fixed');
```

Comment: But this is really unnecessary, as the OP's example works fine and his question about repeating the background position values doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
    'background-position': 'center center',
    'background-attachment': 'fixed'
});
```

Comment: While I'm not saying this wouldn't work, why is it necessary? http://jsfiddle.net/a5vCn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentCSS = $('body').css('background'),
    newBG = 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')',
    newCSS = currentCSS.replace(/url(.*)\)/gi, newBG);

$('body').css('background', newCSS);
```

or just change the background-image, which will not change the other background properties